# Poor speedup with libstdc++ parallel mode quick sort

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, quicksort, libstdc++, std

I cannot get speedup higher than 2 with in-place sorting algorithms (quick sort and balanced quick sort; QS/BQS) from the parallel implementation of libstdc++ (parallel mode). I have tried to run the code on many different systems consisting of from 16 to 24 cores. I have also tried GNU and Intel C++ compilers, even in different versions, always with same results. The speedup around 2 is the same for any number of cores between 2 and max.

On the contrary, multi-way merge sort (MWMS) scales well (speedup around 10 using 16 threads on 16 cores machine). According to J. Singler's presentation *"The GNU libstdc++ parallel mode: Benefit from Multi-Core using the STL"*, their measured speedups for BQS are almost the same as for MWMS (see page 18, http://ls11-www.cs.uni-dortmund.de/people/gutweng/AD08/VO11_parallel_mode_overview.pdf); they observed speedup over 20 with BQS using 32 threads.

Any idea why this happens or what do I wrong?

Comment: Do you call `omp_set_num_threads()` to set the number of threads it should use?  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/parallel_mode_design.html#parallel_mode.design.tuning

Comment: Yes, I do (otherwise, there would be no speedup with MWMS either).

Comment: It might be evident but have you checked to put the openmp flag ?

Comment: @coincoin: Do you mean compiler flag? Yes, I have. I use the very same source code as well as the same build procedure in all 3 cases (QS, BQS, and MWMS). Moreover, there would be probably no speedup without openmp flag, but I observe speedup being 2.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Thanks for reminding me the manual. I have seen it a lot of times, but it did not occur to me until now to try to call `omp_set_nested()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seemingly solved the problem simply by calling:

```
omp_set_nested(1);
```

The documentation is little bit unclear about this requirement. Moreover, I would expect that the library is able to perform the call by itself. Hopefully, this will help also someone else.